# Uploading image to facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph, facebook-page

Is it possible to upload image using the graph api or other method to facebook page ? 
example appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible. Look in Facebook.cpp for an example:

https://github.com/eamocanu/Facebook.Qt.APIs/blob/master/APIs/Facebook.cpp
method: uploadPhoto(..)

The entire API is hosted at https://github.com/eamocanu/Facebook.Qt.APIs
You can also download it from https://github.com/eamocanu/Facebook.Qt.APIs/downloads